# Pen tool not showing anchor points on existing shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made a shape, let's say a rectangle using the pen tool.

I now am trying to make a diagonal line from one corner of the square to the other side.

I press P for pen and am trying to select the anchor point on the top-left corner but I'm unable to see the anchor points or path. I only see guides but without seeing the anchor point, I'm not able to accurately join the paths later.

This is a problem for more complex shapes.

Does anyone know how to fix this? A tutorial I am following shows that if you select the Pen tool it should show all the existing anchors so you can continue drawing from them.

Answer (score 3):

`View > Show Edges`

You probably inadvertently hit the shortcut for it.

Or.. the path *has to be selected* before showing you the anchors and spines. Merely choosing the Pen tool never shows you the edges of unselected objects.

Comment: Thanks, so the path wasn't selected. I thought the anchor points would show up if you just hover over the path because otherwise it's hard to click accurately on the existing path. But it seems like that's just how it is. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Enabling the smart guides will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Go to "View" > then click "Smart Guides"

Sorry for the late answer.